# Selenium can't find element, while I can find it in the HTML code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to type in a word in a searchbar and then select a random suggested searchword and click on it. However, I am stuck since selenium doesn't seem to find the list of suggested searchwords. The code that I am using looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='searchfor']")

search.send_keys("test")


suggestions = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='siteSearch']/wsp-search-suggestions/ul[2]/li")))
```

However, when I use the XPATH to find the elements in the HTML code I do find them:
[as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsMRU.png)

I am getting a TimeoutException error. Does anyone have an idea of what I am missing?

UPDATE: When I opened the inspect in Chrome, the searchbar moved from its full-screen position to another position. Apparently the class of the search suggestions also changes then. So by just putting the inspect pane on the bottom of the page I was able to find the correct class and now it works!

Comment: Can you show the link to the site, so we can check how it works?

Comment: @Niels Tooth: check if there is a frame in your HTML and your element is within the frame.

Comment: @Invizi thank you for your comment. The website I am looking at is https://www.bol.com/be/nl/

Comment: @GauravLad Thank you for your answer! I am not sure what you mean by frame (sorry, I am really not into HTML). The list of elements is grouped under a class 'wsp-suggest-group' if that is what you mean?

Comment: @NielsTooth: 'wsp-suggest-group' sounds like a frame, try google for how to handle frames in selenium. search for <frame> tag in your HTML and see if required element is inside it.

Comment: Pro tip: Always maximize your window in selenium first (using `driver.maximize_window()` ) before anything else to avoid issues like dynamic classes that come with responsive behaviour